# XML FOLDER - wp_insert_post - how to assign XML variables to post

Tags: wp-insert-post, xml

I'm trying to repurpose a code that worked for CSV files to do the same for XML-> That is import all files in the folder and create Wordpress custom posts(cikkek).
So, I managed to parse the XML files in the given folder and get the right variables that I need:

```
            $posttitle = $xml->THIR->CIM[0];
            $postlead = $xml->THIR->LEAD[0];
            $postcontent = $xml->THIR->HIRSZOVEG[0];
```

Now my question is, how can I assign these variables to the last part of the code (line 65 - wp_insert_post).
I tried simply replacing '$post["title]",' with '$posttitle,' but the code does not seem to run.

Here's the whole code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Create and insert posts from XML files
 */
add_action( "admin_init", function() {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! isset( $_GET["insert_mti_posts"] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // CPT SETTINGS
    $mti = array(
        "custom-post-type" => "cikkek"
    );

    // Get the data from all those XMLs!
    $posts = function() {
        $data = array();
        $errors = array();

        // Get array of XML files
        $xmlfiles =  glob( __DIR__ . "/data/*.xml" );

        foreach ( $xmlfiles as $xmlfile ) {

            $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
            $posttitle = $xml->THIR->CIM[0];
            $postlead = $xml->THIR->LEAD[0];
            $postcontent = $xml->THIR->HIRSZOVEG[0];

        };

            if ( ! empty( $errors ) ) {
                // ... do stuff with the errors
            }

        return $data;
    };

    // Simple check to see if the current post exists within the
    //  database. This isn't very efficient, but it works.
    $post_exists = function( $title ) use ( $wpdb, $mti ) {

        // Get an array of all posts within our custom post type
    $posts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = '{$mti["custom-post-type"]}'" );

        // Check if the passed title exists in array
    return in_array( $title, $posts );
    };

    foreach ( $posts() as $post ) {

        // If the post exists, skip this post and go to the next one
        if ( $post_exists( $post["title"] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // Insert the post into the database
        $post["id"] = wp_insert_post( array(
            "post_title" => $post["title"],
            "post_content" => $post["content"],
            "post_type" => $mti["custom-post-type"],
            "post_status" => "draft"
        ));
    }

});
```

*EDIT: I think the main issue is with $data. It should return an associative array like:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        "title" => $posttitle[0],
        "content" => $postcontent[0],
        "description" => $postlead[0],


      
    ),
    1 => array(
        "title" => $posttitle[1],
        "content" => $postcontent[1],
        "description" => $postlead[1],
       
    ),
    // ...
);
```

The issue is I don't know how to pass it this info.

Hope I explained it clearly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read, can you fix the indenting?

Comment: Sure, better now? Thanks for having a look!

Comment: A little but not much, most of the code still has has incorrect indentation, there are functions with contents that aren't indented at all. Anywhere inside a curly bracket needs to be indented one level deeper than its surroundings

Comment: Had another go at it, and simplified the code as well.

Comment: Are there sections missing? e.g. the `$posts` function has a data array, but you never add anything to it, it's just an empty array. Also the `$post_exists` is missing a level of indenting, which editor are you using to code, your editor should do all of this for you automatically

Comment: Hi Tom! I'm using VSCode with phpfmt for formatting. It does have some weird quirks but I haven't come across anything better. Beautify and Prettier don't do php as far as I know. Yes, that is exactly the missing part of the solution. I don't know how to feed the $data variable (which will equal the $posts you mentioned) my xml variables like I explain at the end of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have 2 separate loops or why the `$posts` function exists. Why assign the XML variables to `$data` when you can just put `wp_insert_post` straight into the loop? Adding the data to  `$data` doesn't sound like a WordPress problem, it sounds like a beginner level PHP problem.  I'm not sure what the missing piece you are missing is, wether it's adding an array to another array, appending,  or creating an array with keys e.g.  `[ 'foo' => 'bar' ]` but generic PHP questions should go on stackoverflow. My advice? Your variables containing functions are unnecessary and confusing

Comment: In which case, there is a literal example of the solution to your problem in your code inside the `wp_insert_post` call. Also, you should use named functions, they're confusing your code formatters and making the code significantly harder to understand while providing no benefits